# Where does subversion download a newly checked out project to?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have just gotten svn and checked out my first project from the internet.  Normally when I'm working with SVN, I have created the project locally.  I downloaded the trunk with svn co

> https://somethingcool.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/somethingcool

Where have all of the files downloaded to?  It must be the default..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're normally downloaded into a directory named after the last segment of the URL, so with your example URL it would be somethingcool. The directory is located where you ran the checkout command.

You can also specify a different directory, e.g.:

```
svn co https://svn.example.org/something path/to/any/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a destination path, SVN will checkout in a directory named after the last part of the URL. Assuming you where in **C:\Users\Chris** when you checkout out, the output would have been **C:\Users\Chris\somethingcool**.